# ruby on rails concurrent adds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, locking

I have a model with a has_many association. The association also has an :after_add component which increments a counter. I was wondering how this would play out in a concurrent scenario (e.g. when two different instances are added to the has_many at the exact same time). Would the counter increase by 2? Does rails internally get a lock, increment, and release the lock? Is the add and :after_add callback seen as one atomic action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using the increment methods and not doing a SELECT, increment in Ruby, then UPDATE, you should be fine. More info: [rails 3 & activerecord: do I need to take special record locking precautions to update a counter field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313843/rails-3-activerecord-do-i-need-to-take-special-record-locking-precautions-to-u/6313893#6313893)

Comment: So it seems that the increment method on a model instance doesn't save the instance after incrementing. I need to save separately, which can cause concurrency issues. If I use increment_counter class method, it seems to work. Is there a reason the instance method, increment, doesn't work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Another issue that I am facing with increment_counter is that if I have a hbtm association with :uniq => true, the counter is even incremented upon duplicate adds. Before I used to set the counter column to the length of the hbtm association but, as you said, that uses a select and update, which is not concurrent friendly. How do I go about only incrementing only upon UNIQUE adds? Thanks.

Comment: I could first add_index via rails migration the to specify the unique cols. Is that the recommended approach take care of this?

Comment: The `Model#increment!` method is just doing the updating in Ruby. It's implemented independently of the `*_counter(s)` methods. The `increment_counter` method calls `update_counters` which will make an intelligent SQL query. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters

Comment: If you're just trying to keep track of how many associated objects exist, you shouldn't be doing any of this manually. You should just look into the built-in counter-cache.

Comment: In my experience, :counter_cache has not be available in habtm associations, which is why I am doing it manually for those types.